# Converting list items from string to int(Python)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, int

I have a list:

```
Student_Grades = ['56', '49', '63']
```

and I want to convert each of the entries to integers so that I can calculate an average.

Here's my code for converting:

```
for i in Student_Grades:
    Student_Grades = [int(i)]
```

I keep getting the error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '56,'
```

and I don't know what to do.

Here is my full code on how I got Student_Grades
Choose_File = str(input("Please enter the exact name of the file to be read in (including file extention) : "))

```
with open(Choose_File, "r") as datafile:
    counter = 1
    x = 1
    Student_Grades = []
    Read = datafile.readlines()
    info = Read[counter]
    Split_info = info.split()
    n = len(Split_info)


    while x < n:
        Student_Grades.append(Split_info[x])
        x = x + 2
```

The textfile has the format 'MECN1234 56, MECN1357 49, MATH1111 63'

Comment: Your list does *not* contain just `'56'`; there is a comma there too. How did you *create* `Student_Grades`?

Comment: I read in a few lines from a textfile with the format: MECN1234 56, MECN1357 49, MATH1111 63 I then split the lines using .split() and then appended the Student_Grades list with every 2nd entry from the split list (which were the grades).

Comment: Here's my full code: Choose_File = str(input("Please enter the exact name of the file to be read in (including file extention) : "))

with open(Choose_File, "r") as datafile:
    counter = 1
    x = 1
    Student_Grades = []
    Read = datafile.readlines()
    info = Read[counter]
    Split_info = info.split()
    n = len(Split_info)

    
    while x < n:
        Student_Grades.append(Split_info[x])
        x = x + 2

Comment: @user3576929 larger pieces of codes is better to add to your question (if it does not change your question), it is much more readable.

Comment: How would I deal with that comma?

Comment: This will solve your problem in 1 line using list comprehension

test = 'MECN1234 56, MECN1357 49, MATH1111 63'


numbers = [int(entry.split()[-1]) for entry in test.split(',')]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should do this:

```
for i in range(len(Student_Grades)):
    Student_Grades[i] = int(Student_Grades[i])
```

Comment: I think she wants to update the list.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Yes, I changed it.

Answer (score 21):

Apply `int` on each item in the list and return it as a list:

```
>>> StudentGrades = ['56', '49', '63']
>>> res = list(map(int, StudentGrades)) # this call works for Python 2.x as well as for 3.x
>>> print res
[56, 49, 63]
```

### Note about `map` differences in Python 2 and 3

In Python 2.x `map` returns directly the list, so you may use

```
>>> res = map(int, StudentGrades)
```

but in Python 3.x `map` returns an iterator, so to get real list, it must be wrapped into `list` call:

```
>>> res = list(map(int, StudentGrades))
```

The later way works well in both version of Python

Comment: This returned <map object at 0x00000000032BD518> and I'm not quite sure what this means. Forgive me, I'm new to programming

Comment: @user3576929, you must be using Python 3 and @Jan is using python 2.  You can fix this by using `list(map(int, StudentGrades))`

Comment: @askewchan Thanks for your comment, I updated my answer to be Python 2 and 3 compatible

Answer (score 8):

```
In [7]:

Student_Grades = ['56', '49', '63']
new_list = [int(i) for i in Student_Grades]
print(new_list)
[56, 49, 63]
```